# How to filter messages using Parameter values

Tags: xpath

I am trying to **deselect** files based on the value of the param name "filter_param" within the  section. Example input file:

```
<What>
    <Param name="filter_param"  value="1" />
    <Param name="other_param"  value="2" />
    <Param name="yet_other_param"  value="1" />
...
</What>
```

The 'filter_param' can have any integer value between 1 and 100 and I am trying to get rid of only the ones that have certain values (e.g. 1 and 2). I am trying filters like

```
"//Param[@name='What/filter_param' and @value!=1] and //Param[@name='What/filter_param' and @value!=2]"
```

but without success... Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `and` inside predicates:

```
//Param[@name="..." and @value != 1 and @value != 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, assuming your xml looks like this:

```
<What>
    <Param name="filter_param"  value="1" />
    <Param name="other_param"  value="2" />
    <Param name="yet_other_param"  value="1" />
    <Param name="filter_param"  value="100" />
</What>
```

This xpath expression

```
//What/Param[not(.[@name="filter_param"][@value<3])]
```

should output:

```
<Param name="other_param" value="2"/>
<Param name="yet_other_param" value="1"/>
<Param name="filter_param" value="100"/>
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

In XPath 2.0 you can do

```
//Param[@name="filter_param" and not(@value=(1, 2))]
```

to select `Param` node *that contains `name` attribute that equals to `"filter_param"` and `value` attribute is not equal to `1`, not equal to `2`*

Comment: Thanks! Certainly very helpful in general. unfortunately, the values I need to filter are not continuous...